# How do I go about making a opacity mask for the borders of the planar mesh?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes, masking

I want to make a procedural black and white mask/matte for planar objects' boundaries to use as a texture blending component.

[image: Kinda like this rectangular gradient mask I made in Photoshop]

Something like this, but I did this in Photoshop, and obviously I want to do it in blender.
I've experimented with Splitting the UV into X and Y and then using "Ping-Pong" function in the maths nodes and then combining the two together to get the result, while yes, this certainly works for a square plane, how about a planar object that isn't a square shape? But a different shape. Is there any way to make a mask from the boundary of a mesh, boundary of the UV, perhaps?

Comment: can u pls provide a blend file, so we know how your shape looks like? because that's essential for the solution. Also the UV Map is important, if we wanna provide a shader solution. The geometry is important, if we wanna provide a GN solution. thx.